# Pandas Shaping Data for Covariance

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, covariance

I need to conduct a simple covariance analysis in a time series. My raw data comes in the shape like this:

```
WEEK_END_DATE              TITLE_SHORT          SALES  
2012-02-25 00:00:00.000000 "Bob" (EBK)         1
                           "Bob" (EBK)         1
2012-03-31 00:00:00.000000 "Bob" (EBK)         1
                           "Bob" (EBK)         1
2012-03-03 00:00:00.000000 "Sally" (EBK)          1
2012-03-10 00:00:00.000000 "Sally" (EBK)          1
2012-03-17 00:00:00.000000 "Sally" (EBK)          1
                           "Sally" (EBK)          1
2012-04-07 00:00:00.000000 "Sally" (EBK)          1
```

As you can see, there are some duplicates. Unless I'm missing something, I need this data to become a set of vectors for each title, so that I can use numpy.cov.

Question:

How do I find duplicates in date and name and AGGREGATE them by sum? I've been trying to use pandas groupby WEEK_END_DATE and TITTLE_SHORT but it comes out indexed in a way that I don't understand.

EDIT:
To be specific, when I try `df.groupby(["WEEK_END_DATE", "TITLE_SHORT"])`, I get this:

```
>df.ix[0:3]

WEEK_END_DATE               TITLE_SHORT               
2012-02-04 00:00:00.000000  'SALEM'S LOT (EBK)            <pandas.core.indexing._NDFrameIndexer object a...
                            'TIS THE SEASON! (EBK)        <pandas.core.indexing._NDFrameIndexer object a...
                            (NOT THAT YOU ASKED) (EBK)    <pandas.core.indexing._NDFrameIndexer object a...
dtype: object
```

and trying to select `df.ix[1,]` gets this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0rc1_20130415-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/pandas/core/series.py", line 613, in __getitem__
    return self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0rc1_20130415-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/pandas/core/index.py", line 1630, in get_value
    loc = self.get_loc(key)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0rc1_20130415-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/pandas/core/index.py", line 2285, in get_loc
    result = slice(*self.slice_locs(key, key))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0rc1_20130415-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/pandas/core/index.py", line 2226, in slice_locs
    start_slice = self._partial_tup_index(start, side='left')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0rc1_20130415-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/pandas/core/index.py", line 2250, in _partial_tup_index
    raise Exception('Level type mismatch: %s' % lab)
Exception: Level type mismatch: 3
```

Comment: By "raw data", do you mean that's what your input file looks like?

Comment: can you post the index that you don't understand please?

Comment: DSM- yes, input file. Ryan- right on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain I know what's going on, but here's what I'd start with.  First, get the data (which looks fixed-width to me):

```
>>> df = pd.read_fwf("weekend.dat", widths=(26, 20, 9), parse_dates=[0])
>>> df = df.fillna(method="ffill")
>>> df
        WEEK_END_DATE    TITLE_SHORT  SALES
0 2012-02-25 00:00:00    "Bob" (EBK)      1
1 2012-02-25 00:00:00    "Bob" (EBK)      1
2 2012-03-31 00:00:00    "Bob" (EBK)      1
3 2012-03-31 00:00:00    "Bob" (EBK)      1
4 2012-03-03 00:00:00  "Sally" (EBK)      1
5 2012-03-10 00:00:00  "Sally" (EBK)      1
6 2012-03-17 00:00:00  "Sally" (EBK)      1
7 2012-03-17 00:00:00  "Sally" (EBK)      1
8 2012-04-07 00:00:00  "Sally" (EBK)      1
```

Then aggregate the dups:

```
>>> g = df.groupby(["WEEK_END_DATE", "TITLE_SHORT"]).sum().reset_index()
>>> g
        WEEK_END_DATE    TITLE_SHORT  SALES
0 2012-02-25 00:00:00    "Bob" (EBK)      2
1 2012-03-03 00:00:00  "Sally" (EBK)      1
2 2012-03-10 00:00:00  "Sally" (EBK)      1
3 2012-03-17 00:00:00  "Sally" (EBK)      2
4 2012-03-31 00:00:00    "Bob" (EBK)      2
5 2012-04-07 00:00:00  "Sally" (EBK)      1
```

And then do whatever `cov` stuff you need to (note that `cov` is a Series/DataFrame/GroupBy method too, so you shouldn't need to call `np.cov` specifially).

Comment: That worked! I think the reset_index was the key-- it was getting messed up when I first tried to do it. Should I ask a separate question about the covar part?